# A card player with $\$32$ wins $4$ of $7$ games, where he and his opponent bet $50\%$ of his money each time. How much money does he have in the end?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, puzzle, gambling

Found the following problem related to "tricky" problems from elementary mathematics:

> Mr. White and Mr. Green were playing cards. Mr. White made the suggestion: “Let’s play for money. For each game we play the bet would be 50% of all the money you have in your pocket.”
>
> When Mr. Green hesitated, Mr. White added: "Your skills are greater that mine in this game; usually you win this game more frequently than I do."
>
> Mr. Green agreed. He said he had 32 dollars. The initial bet for the first game was 16 dollars. They played 7 games, four of which were won by the better player, Mr. Green.
>
> How much money did Mr. Green have after these seven games?

**What was checked**

After research it turns out that Math Stack Exchange platform does not recently contain any notices related to such problem. Because of that I figured out that for the purpose of expansion of the content of this platform  I am going to post such question with my attempt (provided below).

**Attempt of solution**

Given model of game implies:

- increase of size of posession by a factor of $\frac{3}{2}$ in the case of win
- decrease of size of posession by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in the case of defeat

Since there are $4$ wins and $3$ defeats and since we are only interested in seeing final outcome from given session of $7$ games, then using implications from rule of product from combinatoris, the total quantity of money from the session of $7$ completed games in the case of Mr. Green is:

$$
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{4} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3} \cdot 32 = \frac{81}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{8} \cdot 32 = \frac{81}{4} = 20 \frac{1}{4} [\text{dollars}] 
$$

Think that this solves the problem.

**Aim**

If anyone would post a feedback regarding given attempt to this problem, then I think that this would target for enriching a content of Math Stack Exchange platform. Simple as that as this is neither homework nor academic coursework nor assessed problem.

Comment: This post doesn't really improve the site. It would be better if you shared with us your attempt to solve the problem and where you are stuck.

Comment: @JohnDouma will do then.

Comment: Updated content with shared attempt.

Comment: It is unclear whether that first $16 bet refers to Mr Green's first bet or Mr Green AND Mr White's first bets. Either way, order matters: suppose that they both started with the same amount and that Mr Green won the first 4 games and lost the last 3. Then his total after the first game is 32+16 = 48; after the second, it's 56, then 60, then 62. Losing the next 3 games leaves him with 31, 15.5, then 7.75. Now suppose instead that he won the first 2 and the last 2 games and lost the rest. Then his running total would be 48, 56, 28, 14, 7, 35.5, 49.75. Both scenarios have the same number of wins

Comment: (Cont) and losses for Mr Green, but 7.75 ≠ 49.75. So order does matter and without knowing it, there's no unique solution to the problem. Unless of course I've way overthought it, but my interpretation is only based on the assumption that Messrs Green and White start with the same amount of money. In the absence of solid information that seems like a pretty reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is totally correct, don't listen to the comments, and here's why: multiplication is commutative! You've figured out that losing is multiplying by $\frac 1 2$ and winning is $\frac 3 2$, thus, since multiplication is commutative, order doesn't matter! Here's an example:
$((((((32×\frac 1 2)×\frac 3 2)×\frac 3 2)×\frac 1 2)×\frac 3 2)×\frac 1 2)×\frac 3 2$
$=32×(\frac 3 2)^4×(\frac 1 2)^3=20+\frac 1 4$

QED